# Open browser on notification doesn't work unless app is open

Tags: android

I have this code on my GcmListenerService

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Log.d("MESSAGE RECEIVED", data.toString());
    try {
        Bundle notification = (Bundle) data.get("notification");
        if (notification != null) {

            String title = notification.getString("title");
            String text = notification.getString("body");
            String target = notification.getString("target");


            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(target));
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
            super.onMessageReceived(from, data);
        }
    } catch (Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The intent works great when the app is open, but if you click the notification When the app is closed, then the notification just open my app (not the browser as i expected).

Any ideas?